# erro al enviar una solicitud post en wordpress

Tags: api, wordpress

Estoy teniendo problemas al enviar una solicitud post a una api, tengo que mandarle los ids de los atributos de un producto, cree el array pero a la hora de mandarlo me da error 400, seguramente no lo estoy mandando en el formato correcto

```
                // Aisgnamos los atributos al producto
                $inserProduct->set_attributes( $attributes );
    
                $attributes_ids = json_encode( $attributes_ids ); // [5,600,6,70,40]
    
//              $productOptions = array("productOptions" => $attributes_ids);
    
                $args = array(
                  'headers' => array(
                     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                     'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Inpid2RZR1JwaUUtc0RrYUhESktFZSJ9'
                  ),
                    'body' => array("productOptions" => $attributes_ids)
                );
    
                // Hacemos una llamada para obtener las diferentes variantes que tiene el producto
                $price_variant = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_post('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/price/' . $product_id . '/us', $args));
                $price_variant = json_decode( $price_variant );
    
                echo('<pre>');
                var_dump($price_variant);               
                echo('</pre>');
                die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion

```
// Aisgnamos los atributos al producto
                $inserProduct->set_attributes( $attributes );
                
                $productOptions = array(
                    'productOptions' => $attributes_ids
                );
    
                $args2 = array(
                  'headers' => array(
                     'method'      => 'POST',
                     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                     'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Inpid2RZR1JwaUUtc0RrYUhESktFZSJ9'
                  ),
                    'body' => json_encode($productOptions)
                );
    
                // Hacemos una llamada para obtener las diferentes variantes que tiene el producto
                $price_variant = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_post('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/price/' . $product_id . '/us', $args2));
                $price_variant = json_decode( $price_variant );
    
                echo('<pre>');
                var_dump($price_variant);       
                echo('</pre>');
                die();
```